# Coverage on Android Build

Tags: android, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco

I am trying to get coverage for android project based on gradle.

So I add for my application build.gradle

```
jacoco { }
```

and

`testCoverageEnabled true`

inside debug.

This is **working ok**. I can get a report with `createDebugCoverageReport` or `connectedCheck`.

The problem is that debug builds are normally used by developers to run and test app. So having code coverage enabled inside that build might slow a build and probably not needed for this usage.

So I thought I will add new configuratuon

```
coverage {
            initWith buildTypes.debug
            testCoverageEnabled true
}
```

Unfortunately there is no `createCoverageCoverageReport` and `connectedCheck` does not run the coverage type.

When I decompile apk with dex2jar and look inside with jd-gui I see jacoco calls inside debug and coverage so it is there but it is not launched by gradle plugin for coverage.

This makes me think that coverage is only hardcoded for debug builds.

The questions are:
1. Is my thinking that I need a coverage buildType is ok ? I think debug build should be separate of build with coverage
2. Is jacoco report only available in debug build? If not how to run it on coverage type?
3. Where I can find source code of Jacoco extension. I would like to see the implemetnation ? I found [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base) and `build-system/gradle-core/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/coverage/JacocoExtension.groovy` but I have a feeling thtat it is not the one used by gradle plugin.

[Repository I am trying this on](https://github.com/marekdef/TestFlavors)

Answer (score 1):

I got partial answer from the Gradle team
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.adt.devel/5978

basically you need to define coverage as a test build this is done via

`android {
   testBuildType "coverage"
}`

in `build.gradle`. This answers only why coverage goals where not present in coverage build type.